# Getting the corresponding column in a different table MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way where in I could use the sub_name, instead of the sub_id?

This is my code..

```
echo "<table border=1 align=center><tr class=style2><td>Date<td>Student Name <td> Subject <td> Score";

$sortQuery = mysql_query("select * from mst_adminresult",$cn) or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_row($sortQuery))
{
    echo "<tr class=style8><td>$row[5]<td>$row[1] <td align=center> $row[4] <td align=center> $row[3]/20";   
}
echo "</table>";
```

this code shows a result of all the exam taken. In the `Subject` it's output is the subject ID. I'm just wondering if there is any way I could get its subject name. The subject name is in different table.

adminresult_tbl

```
CREATE TABLE `mst_adminresult` (
  `adminResultID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `login` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `test_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `test_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

subjecet_tbl

```
CREATE TABLE `mst_subject` (
  `sub_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `sub_name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_desc` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

test_tbl

```
CREATE TABLE `mst_test` (
  `test_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `sub_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `test_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_que` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The flow of the program is, when the user takes an exam, the user will be redirected to a page where all the subjects are listed, then the user will choose the subject she wants to take, after that, a list of tests will show, then the user will choose again and that's when the user can have the quiz.

In the list of subjects, I've called the `subject_tbl`. In the list of test, the `test_tbl`. When the user is finished taking the exam, it will store in the `adminresult_tbl`

Comment: in mst_adminresult there is no column for sub_id i am not able to see sub_id column

Comment: Stop using PHP's long-since deprecated mysql_ API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JOIN the 3 tables. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM mst_adminresult m
JOIN test_tbl t ON t.test_id = m.test_id
JOIN subject_tbl s ON s.sub_id = t.sub_id;
```

Comment: thank you!!! :D may i ask one more question..i'm still learning on this database...can you explain to me what is the purpose of that 'm' and that t.test_id... your whole code if it is okay. thank you

Comment: `m` there is being used as table alias (see also http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp ). MySQL simply allows you to miss out the `AS`.

Answer (score 0):

As depicted by @PrinceG, you may use the [JOIN syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to read values from other tables. To stay in the format of your coding, the SQL statement should read something like this:

```
SELECT ar.*, s.sub_name 
   FROM mst_adminresult AS ar
      LEFT JOIN mst_test AS t ON t.test_id = ar.test_id
      LEFT JOIN mst_subject AS s ON s.sub_id = t.sub_id;
```

Doing so will allow you to access the subject's name via `$row[6]`.

However, also note that your database modelling is quite risky to do so:

- You did not specify any [primary key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html) on your master data (e.g. `mst_subject` and `mst_test`) tables. This may lead to severe data inconsistencies if not handled carefully. Introducing primary keys are a very good habit for good reasons - for example see http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-primary-key/
- There is not [referential integrity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) set up for your tables, although the underlying DB engine InnoDB supports it. Thus, it may happen - for instance - that you have a `test_id` of 5 in `mst_adminresult`, which does not have a corresponding record in `mst_test`. As the statement above uses `LEFT JOIN`s, this would not suppress your record in the resultset returned, but a `NULL` value would show up in PHP. However, I doubt that this is intentional in your case. Instead, I would assume that it was a better approach that the DB would raise an error already when inserting a record into `mst_adminresult` for which no test is provided so far in `mst_test`. 
  The same pattern also applies to `mst_subject` in regards to `mst_test`.

In sum, you may find articles like that one on [ER Modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) interesting.